# Adding <script> tag to navigator.clipboard.writeText

Tags: javascript

I have a function to copy some code into the clipboard:

```
function copyCodeToClipboard() {
    htmlCode = "<form id='myForm'>...</form>"
    cssCode = "body {font-weight: bold}";
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(htmlCode + "<style>" + cssCode + "</style>");
}
```

This works fine.

I want to include Google ReCaptcha into it with a bunch of script:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<script>
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    grecaptcha.reset();
    grecaptcha.execute();
  });
</script>
```

But when I try something like:

```
var recaptchaScript = '<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script><script>document.getElementById("myForm").submit(function (event) {...});</script>';

function copyCodeToClipboard() {
    ...
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(recaptchaScript + htmlCode + "<style>" + cssCode + "</style>");
}
```

I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

How can I copy the script text to the clipboard?

Comment: too lazy to find a dupe, but it is because of the </script> in the string. Browser parser has no clue that is in a string and not the closing HTML tag. So you need to break it up.  `...</ ' + + 'script>`

Comment: @epascarello - correct. Thanks. Had to add `...</ ' + "" + 'script>` though or it return NAN

Comment: whoops.... I hit an extra + when typing....